Unable to publish my pbix file to PBI service (error: a dataset or report already exists and is setup with cloud refresh)
I am unable to update my online PBI URL with latest pbix.
I generally just do a manual refresh (using publish button) but I am seeing this error about a cloud refresh being setup which is strange.
Trying to publish a report by overwriting an existing one.
Initial error
ERROR IN SEMANTIC MODEL
disabled cloud connections
